# Counting unique values works directly in shell but not in backticks

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out why this works from the command line however does not when it is in a variable, I am trying to count the number of unique occurrences of a number,

```
$ echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | tr , \\n | sort -u | wc -l
5
$ test=`echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | tr , \\n | sort -u | wc -l`
$ echo $test
1
```

I am assuming that it is seen as one line when in a variable but unsure why and how to address it?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you could also implement this in pure bash, with no `sort`, `tr` or `wc`. Setting up a pipeline has a fair bit of overhead, on the timescale of shell command execution; invoking external commands likewise (even if once they're running those external commands actually execute faster than an implementation using builtins would).

Comment: Example: `s=1,1,2,3,4,5; declare -a vals=( ); while read -r -d, val; do vals[$val]=1; done <<<"$s"; echo "${#vals[@]}"` -- though note that to work with non-numeric keys, you would need bash 4.0 or newer and to use `declare -A` rather than `declare -a`.

Answer (score 3):

you may see what is happening by putting `set -x`:

```
$ test=`set -x; echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | tr , \\n | sort -u | wc -l`
++ echo 1,1,2,3,4,5
++ tr , n
++ wc -l
```

here you see that the `\n` became `n`

the escape of `\n` fails; try

```
test=`echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | tr , '\n' | sort -u | wc -l`
```

the quotes will prevent the `\' to fade away

or even

```
 test=$(echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | tr , '\n' | sort -u | wc -l)
```

as we usually prefere $() to backquotes that can cause some other kind of trouble

Comment: I would also suggest using `$()` syntax instead of backticks -- fixes not only the immediate problem with backslashes, but also reads easier and nests better.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can avoid all the piped commands:

```
count=$(echo 1,1,2,3,4,5 | awk -v RS=, '!seen[$1]++{c++} END{print c}')
echo $count
5
```